# Python XML Parsing - Get XML File Name

Tags: python, xml, csv, parsing, elementtree

I have a working Python 2.7 script which parses all XML files found in the same directory, and saves them to a CSV file.

---

### Question

How can I modify the below code to show (in the CSV output file) which XML file the parsed record came from?

---

### Sample XML files

*Fruit1.xml*

```
<CASES>
  <CASE
      Fruit="Apple"
      Color="Red">
  </CASE>
  <CASE
      Fruit="Pear"
      Color="Yellow">
  </CASE>
</CASES>
```

*Fruit2.xml*

```
<CASES>
  <CASE
      Fruit="Banana"
      Color="Yellow">
  </CASE>
  <CASE
      Fruit="Orange"
      Color="Orange">
  </CASE>
</CASES>
```

### Current Code

```
from itertools import izip
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import os
import csv

def run(files):
    first = None
    for filename in os.listdir(files):
        if filename.endswith('.xml'):
            e = et.parse(filename).getroot()
            if first is None: first = e
            else: first.extend(e)
    return first

fruit = []
color = []

e = run(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))

for x in e.findall('CASE'): fruit.append(x.get('Fruit'))
for x in e.findall('CASE'): color.append(x.get('Color'))

with open('parsed.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
    fieldnames = ["fruit","color"]
    writer = csv.writer(myfile)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    writer.writerows(izip(fruit,color))
```

#### Current Output

```
+--------+--------+
| fruit  | color  |
+--------+--------+
| Apple  | Red    |
| Pear   | Yellow |
| Banana | Yellow |
| Orange | Orange |
+--------+--------+
```

#### Desired Output

```
+--------+--------+------------+
| fruit  | color  |  filename  |
+--------+--------+------------+
| Apple  | Red    | fruit1.xml |
| Pear   | Yellow | fruit1.xml |
| Banana | Yellow | fruit2.xml |
| Orange | Orange | fruit2.xml |
+--------+--------+------------+
```

---

I've tried using a tuple to pair the XML file name with the parsed XML elements, but wasn't able to get this to work.

Comment: Why do the XML-handling and the filename-handling aspects of your code have anything whatsoever to do with each other? The whole "take the root of the first element and extend it" design is... an option that works, I suppose, but you could just as easily have your code return a map of the form `{ filename: element_root }`.

Comment: Even better, `{ filename: (fruit, color) }` or such -- that reduces your memory requirements, too, since you only need to store one parsed DOM at a time.

Comment: ...heck, you could just implement an iterator that returns `(filename, fruit, color)` tuples.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thanks for the input! I'm still pretty new to Python and was confused for a while, but I figured it out and will post the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got this to work:

```
from itertools import izip
import xml.etree.ElementTree as et
import os
import csv

fruit = []
color = []
filenames = []

directory = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))

for filename in os.listdir(directory):
    if filename.endswith('.xml'):
        e = et.parse(filename).getroot()
        for x in e.findall('CASE'): fruit.append(x.get('Fruit'))
        for x in e.findall('CASE'): color.append(x.get('Color'))
        for x in e.findall('CASE'): filenames.append(filename)

with open('parsed.csv', 'wb') as myfile:
    fieldnames = ["fruit","color","filenames"]
    writer = csv.writer(myfile)
    writer.writerow(fieldnames)
    writer.writerows(izip(fruit,color,filenames))
```